# Joomla issue with custom form and file upload

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have created a form in view in default.php. it looks like below:

```
 <form id="import_form" method="post" action="index.php?option=com_jobsearch&task=jobs.import" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <input type="file" name="xml_file" id="xml_file"/>
      <type="submit" id="import_submit" class="import_submit" value="Import"/>  
 </form>
```

I have created a function called `import` (for task) in jobs controller in controllers folder.

```
function import(){
  echo time();die;
}
```

This function is accessible using below url

`index.php?option=com_jobsearch&task=jobs.import`

Also when i upload a small size file it works fine.

But when i upload a file with size 50 MB. it give below error after uploading done.

`0 Invalid controller: name='jobs', format=''`

I have checked `php.ini` and all seems to be fine.

```
max_execution_time=20000
memory_limit=256M
upload_max_filesize=256M
post_max_size=256M
```

*I found that the error shows front template also when I investigated it found that it post the form to front index.php file not on administrator's index.php file.*

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.